# maximum recursion depth reached in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have developed a code for finding max and min using recursion. But as soon as I make a list greater then 6 elements it throws a runtime error.

**RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison**

Here is the below code:

```
def maxmin(a,i,j):
    if(i==j):
        return(a[i],a[j])
    elif(i==j-1):
        if(a[i]>a[j]):
            return(a[i],a[j])
        else:
            return(a[j],a[i])
    else:
        mid =int(i+j/2)
        value1 =maxmin(a,i,mid)
        value2 =maxmin(a,mid+1,j)
        if(value1[0]>value2[0]):
            max=value1[0]
        else:
            max=value2[0]
        if(value1[1]<value2[1]):
            min = value1[1]
        else:
            min=value2[1]
        return(max,min)

import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1000)
a =[2,3,90,0,-9,3]
maxmin(a,0,len(a)-1)
```

I have also increased the limit for recursion but still not working.

I tried another small code by recursion with a stack size of 1000 and its working fine. I think there is some issue in the code. The stack space occupied by the above program is not even 100.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1000)
def fib(n, sum):
    if n < 1:
        return sum
    else:
        return fib(n-1, sum+n)

c = 900
print(fib(c, 0))
```

The second program is working fine while the first is throwing errors.

Comment: it means you're creating an infinite loop

Comment: Is `mid =int(i+j/2)` supposed to be the midpoint between `i` and `j`? because it is not. When you recurse using `mid` you will sometimes be making your range bigger instead of smaller.

Comment: To complete @khelwood comment, you always need to understand if your recursion terminates, and in this case, it doesn't .

Comment: Thanks, issue solved... I forgot to add brackets (i+j)/2

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't use recursion:

```
print(min(a))
print(max(a))
```

Comment: @BornTbeWasted I solved his issue, and he didn't say he is practicing recursion. So now answers that solves the issue is downvoted because of an interpretation in the question?